# Looping through rows in a Pandas dateframe to check values in two separate columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Let's say that I have a dataframe with 6 columns and 4 rows, and a separate list we will call boollist. What I want to do is loop through all of the rows, and then if 2 of the cells in the row contain blank strings I would then append "False" to boollist. Vice-versa, if the row contains less than 2 blank string cells it will append a "True". At the end of the process boollist should have the same length as the number of rows so that it can be added as a new column.

```
         column0    column1    column2    column3    column4    column5
row0     'data'     'data'      'data'    'data'      'data'     'data'
row1     'data'       ''        'data'    'data'      'data'     'data'
row2       ''         ''         ''          ''       'data'       ''
row3     'data'      'data'     'data'     'data'     'data'     'data'
```

In this example, boollist shoud end up containing [True,True,False,True].

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blanks resolve to `False` in a `bool` context.

```
(~df.astype(bool)).sum(1) < 2
```

To be more explicit

```
df.eq('').sum(1) < 2
```

Answer (score 2):

The great thing about pandas is you don't need to loop through anything.

If you don't want to edit your data to count strings as null then you can use applymap to go through your data.

[applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) applys a function elementwise through your dataframe. Within applymap you can use a [lambda function](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk) which will return True if the cell has an empty string. You then sum the empty strings in the row.

```
df.applymap(lambda x: x =='').sum() <2
```

returns a boolean array conditional on the rows with less than two empty strings.

Comment: I am not trying to drop anything though. I just want to check the rows and then append to a separate list. I also do not have any NaNs they are empty strings.

Comment: .isnull does not work with empty strings as null values. Also would there be  a way to have it return an int list with 1's and 0's, or a string list with 'yes' or 'no'? The boolean array was more meant as an arbitrary way of keeping track of results, I apologize for being unclear.

Comment: you can turn empty strings to null values and then use the code,

Comment: Yes, but I was hoping to find a technique that did not involve changing the actual data since blank strings mean something in my dataset. I understand I could go again and replace them after but I am hoping to find a more efficient strategy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147742/discussion-between-tkanno-and-gseelig).